# Angular Conditional in HTML does not like less than or greater than symbols

Tags: angular

Simple question, cannot seem to find an answer...
(this will be a quick 'point' for someone)

I'm looking to have a condition in an Angular 5 ngIf be "less than" some variable.

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="Subject < 4" >
<div class="row" *ngIf="Subject <= 4" >
```

this syntax bombs because "<" - how can I do this? (without having to write function)?

Comment: but what is happening? App is not working or just IDE complains... Seems legit to me

Comment: are u getting any error in console?

Comment: This is right way. Is it not working? or just the IDE syntax error?

Comment: This should work fine.  "bombs" is not an accurate description of an error.  If you need help, please describe what you mean by that.  I'm willing to bet it is a type mismatch.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*ngIf doesn't work with '<=' sign. Need to check equal(==), less than(<) and greater than(>) conditions separately with OR operator.

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="Subject<4 || Subject==4" >
  Row 1 (Rendered when Subject is lesser than or equal to 4)
</div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="Subject>4" >
  Row 2 (Rendered when Subject is greater than 4)
</div>
```

Some IDE might show '<' or '>' sign in as syntax error while writing the code, because these are used for HTML tags also. But, it will not throw any compile or run time error.

Comment: But you do know that OP is not using `=` anywhere right?

Comment: @Antoniossss Edited my answer according to your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Learning thanks for the idea of manipulating the condition

Answer (score 5):

The editor may pickup the `<` as an error.  It's not actually an error in angular to use less than in an `*ngIf`.  **This is likely a red herring so look for the issue elsewhere.**

In my case I had an issue with a null reference.  E.G.

```
<span *ngIf="someArray">
  <span *ngIf="someArray.length < 3" class="keypadOutput">&nbsp;</span>
</span>
```

In some cases `someArray` can be null so I needed to add an outer `*ngIf` check for `someArray`.

Answer (score 3):

Write a simple getter

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="greaterThan(Subject, 4)" >
```

component.ts:

```
public greaterThan(subj: Subject, num: number) {
  return sub < num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="Subject < 4 || Subject = 4" >
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML entities &lt ; and &gt ;

`<div class="row" *ngIf="Subject &lt; 4" >`

Reference :
[https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp#:~:text=To%20display%20a%20less%20than,for%20entity%20numbers%20is%20good.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp#:%7E:text=To%20display%20a%20less%20than,for%20entity%20numbers%20is%20good.)

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="row" *ngIf="4 > Subject">`
`<div class="row" *ngIf="4 >= Subject">`

And you're done
Works perfect for me

Comment: Worked perfect for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HTML code for less than i.e. `&#60;` can be used and it works. For example in your question, please try:

`<div class="row" *ngIf="Subject &#60; 4" >`
`<div class="row" *ngIf="Subject &#60;= 4" >`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a similar template element,

```html
<p *ngFor="let msg of logMessages"
[ngClass]="{greaterThan4Class: (rowCount > 4)}"
>
{{msg}}
</p>
```

, which caused an an html parser error after the build, and caused the app to crash in the browser. The parser interpreted the greater-than symbol in (rowCount > 4) as the close of the opened <p  elemment. It seemed to be caused by TypeScript not being able to locate all the necessary types for Angular.

SOLUTION:
add this setting to tsconfig.json:

```js
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
```

Note: after this change I was unable to reproduce the issue by removing the above. This might also be solved by performing [npm install] on the Angular project.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the ">" and "<" operators with their HTML encodings, "&gt;" and "&lt;", respectively:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="Subject &lt; 4" >

<div class="row" *ngIf="Subject &lt;= 4" >
```